# ¿Cómo descompongo un webmethod de storedprocedure a arreglo en javascript para utilizarlo en google charts?

Tags: javascript, array, webservice, charts

Tengo unos web methodos con procesos almacenados de sql server que llaman ciertas regiones y estados con parametros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   Lo que me entrega algo como lo siguiente

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="IdNorma" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="NumeroNorma" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TituloNorma" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TotalDoc" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Enproceso" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Finalizado" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="_x0025_Enproceso" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="_x0025_Finalizado" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<IdNorma>1</IdNorma>
<NumeroNorma>NOM-001-STPS-2008</NumeroNorma>
<TituloNorma>Edificios, locales e instalaciones </TituloNorma>
<TotalDoc>11</TotalDoc>
<Enproceso>0</Enproceso>
<Finalizado>11</Finalizado>
<_x0025_Enproceso>0</_x0025_Enproceso>
<_x0025_Finalizado>100</_x0025_Finalizado>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<IdNorma>2</IdNorma>
<NumeroNorma>NOM-002-STPS-2010</NumeroNorma>
<TituloNorma>Prevención y protección contra incendios </TituloNorma>
<TotalDoc>1</TotalDoc>
<Enproceso>0</Enproceso>
<Finalizado>1</Finalizado>
<_x0025_Enproceso>0</_x0025_Enproceso>
<_x0025_Finalizado>100</_x0025_Finalizado>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<IdNorma>7</IdNorma>
<NumeroNorma>NOM-010-STPS-1999</NumeroNorma>
<TituloNorma>Contaminantes por sustancias químicas </TituloNorma>
<TotalDoc>1</TotalDoc>
<Enproceso>1</Enproceso>
<Finalizado>0</Finalizado>
<_x0025_Enproceso>100</_x0025_Enproceso>
<_x0025_Finalizado>0</_x0025_Finalizado>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
<IdNorma>8</IdNorma>
<NumeroNorma>NOM-011-STPS-2001</NumeroNorma>
<TituloNorma>Ruido </TituloNorma>
<TotalDoc>2</TotalDoc>
<Enproceso>1</Enproceso>
<Finalizado>1</Finalizado>
<_x0025_Enproceso>50</_x0025_Enproceso>
<_x0025_Finalizado>50</_x0025_Finalizado>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Esa información la convertí en un arreglo anteriormente para utilizarlo con la librería de google charts que es esta

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart?hl=es_419

Y todo bien. Pude hacer la gráfica y todo desde el back solo pasando el método a ésta parte

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%=webmethod%>);
```

Google lo que pide para graficar es algo como esto

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
          ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
          ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
          ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
          ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
          ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
        ]);
```

Ese methodo lleva a un código como el siguiente:

```
public string webmethod(int idRegion)
        {

            try
            {

                SqlConnection conexionSQL = new SqlConnection("conexion");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                sqlCommand.CommandText = "spObtenRegion";
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdRegion", 1);
                cmd.Connection = conexionSQL;
                conexionSQL.Open();



                DataTable Datos = new DataTable();
                Datos.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                conexionSQL.Close();


                string strDatos;

                strDatos = "[['Region', 'Documentos Normativos','En proceso', 'Finalizado', '%En proceso', '%Finalizado'],";


                foreach (DataRow dr in Datos.Rows)
                {
                    strDatos = strDatos + "[";
                    strDatos = strDatos + "'" + dr[0] + "'" + "," + dr[1] + "," + dr[2] + "," + dr[3] + "," + dr[4] + "," + dr[5];
                    strDatos = strDatos + "],";

                }
                strDatos = strDatos + "]";

                return strDatos;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            //finally { sqlConnection.Close(); }
        }
```

y todo bien, pero necesito hacer eso mismo en el script. Solamente la parte de construir los datos a arreglo, porque los métodos de traer la información ya los tengo. Solo que no he tocado casi nada javascript no se como le pasaría el valor del methodo al script para descomponerlo y se lo pase a google charts.

Esto es lo que tengo. Espero que me puedan ayudar

¡OJO! No estoy utilizando para nada json en el código, pero la mayoría de ejemplos que he visto lo ponen en la parte de Data. 
Puros DataSets estoy utilizando

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reportes.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Reportes" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script  type="text/javascript">
        function RegionesConsulta() {
            var options = {
                title: 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
                vAxis: { title: 'Cups' },
                hAxis: { title: 'Month' },
                seriesType: 'bars',
                series: { 5: { type: 'line' } }
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebService1.asmx/stObtenRegiones",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response.d);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                    alert(response.d);

                    var total = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows() ; i++) {
                        total += data.getValue(i, 1);
                    }


                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(RegionesConsulta);






</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="idR" type="button" value="RegionesConsulta" onclick = "RegionesConsulta()" />
        </div>
    <div>
     <div id="chart_div" style="width: 700px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue realizada [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325490/cómo-mostrar-datos-de-un-web-service-en-un-htmlfrontend-y-después-graficarlos) y resulta ser casi idéntica, incluso el nombre del usuario. Si eres la misma persona, te sugiero que hables con algún moderador para aclarar la situación, ya que estarías duplicando contenido. Saludos

Comment: ya amigo thanks